# Export/Import Large SharePoint 2013 Site

Tags: 2013, export, import

I want to export a large subsite (about 80 GB) and import as a site collection. I'm using `Export-SPWeb` such operations and it is working perfect on small sites, but in this large site it didn't work and also it took long time. Can I use `Backup-SPSite` for this? If I use `Backup-SPSite`, can I backup/restart all permissions? Any other ideas?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Backup-SPSite` - will backup your site collection and not sub site.

To Export a subsite you need to use `Export-SPWeb`, you can use below optional parameters to improve performance.

```
CompressionSize Optional System.Int32
```

Sets the maximum file size for the compressed export files. If the total size of the exported package is greater than this size, the exported package will be split into multiple files.

```
NoFileCompression
Optional
System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter
```

Either enables or disables file compression in the export package. The export package is stored in the folder specified by the Path parameter or Identity parameter. We recommend that you use this parameter for performance reasons. If compression is enabled, the export process can increase by approximately 30 percent.

Disable log file with parameter `NoLogFile`

Suppresses the generation of an export log file. If this parameter is not specified, the `Export-SPWeb` cmdlet will generate an export log file in the same location as the export package. The log file uses Unified Logging Service (ULS).
It is recommended to use this parameter. However, for performance reasons, you might not want to generate a log file.

Reference - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm already using NoFileCompression and NoLogFile parameters. But still takes too long .

It takes about 1 hour to export and 4-5 hours to import.

Comment: considering 80 gb of data, it is expected.....!!!

Comment: Yea, it is. I don't want to decrease time to a few minutes. 2 hours could be great.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check SPLongOperation class for long operation. It will help you.

https://nikpatel.net/2011/04/27/use-splongoperation-to-display-sharepoint-processing-page-for-lengthy-operations/